# scrollviewer doesnt scroll to bottom

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

It would be great if someone could help me. I currently have a phone page and I would like to display the images, but somehow my scrollviewer doesnt scroll to the bottom I can only see two rows of Images and after that the scrollviewer doesn't go any further. 
Here is my XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="Details">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Rectangle Fill="Black" Opacity="0.5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="8"/>
                        <StackPanel Margin="15,10,1,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding xxx.Address}" Foreground="White" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold" />
                            <TextBlock Foreground="White">
                        <Run Text="{Binding xxx.Zipcode}" />
                        <Run />
                        <Run Text="{Binding xxx.Location}" />
                            </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="/Assets/xxx.png" Height="50" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,15,0,0" />
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding xxxx.xxx}" Foreground="White" MinHeight="50" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="15,10,1,0" FontSize="22" />
                            <TextBlock Text="xxxx" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,0,1,10" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="/Assets/xxx.png" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Height="50" Margin="10" />
                        <TextBlock Text="xxx:" Margin="15,10,1,0" Foreground="#FFD8051E" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="xxxx:" Margin="15,10,1,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="15,10,1,0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" >
                            <Run Text="{Binding xxx}" />
                            <Run Text=" m" />
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="xxxx:" Margin="15,10,1,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding xxxx}" Margin="15,10,1,0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" />
                        <TextBlock Text="xxxx:" Margin="15,10,1,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="6" />
                        <ItemsControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="7" ItemsSource="{Binding xxxx}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <tool:WrapPanel />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Margin="10" Source="{Binding .,Converter={StaticResource xxxxx}}" Height="100" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </Grid>
                </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: What is your scrollviewer contained in?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your ScrollViewer Properties.

there should be some more definition

```
 <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1"
 Name="Details"
 VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" AllowDrop="False" ManipulationMode="Control">
```

Comment: Since there is no full XML Code. i suggest you to try this. just try 1st VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" property

Comment: Thanks for answering, but most of those properties are automatically set. I added the ManipulationMode="Control" property and tested just to be sure the other properties too, but it didn't work. Also I added the visible property for the verticalscrollbar and set that to visible, no luck however

Comment: try this ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" if it doesn't work then try ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto". because i cannot assume the correct answer since i didn't try on a mock sample. but these are the problems mostly occur

Comment: Sometimes internal Blocks will cause the problem which is very hard to figure out. Let me know if it works then i'll correct the answer

Comment: Have you treied setting the height property of the scrollviewer?